# Voting system using Microsoft Access

Tags: database, ms-access

thanks for passing by.

I just have two questions. I am on college and I need a bit of help.

I need to do a voting system using Microsoft Access, I have two problems:

1) I don't know how to "Add 1" to the field
2) I can't find a way to avoid the user from selecting more than one candidate (Using checkboxes)

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Comando25_Click()
Dim Check1 As Boolean
Dim Check2 As Boolean
Dim Check3 As Boolean
Dim Check4 As Boolean

 If (Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3 = True & Me.Check4 = True) Then
 MsgBox "You can't select them all, you can only choose one"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If

If (Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3) = True Then
MsgBox "You can't select three, you can only choose one"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If

 If (Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check2 = True) Then
MsgBox "You can't select two, you can only choose one"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If

 If (Me.Check2 = True & Me.Check3 = True) Then
MsgBox "You can't select two, you can only choose one"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If

  If (Me.Check1 = True & Me.Check3) = True Then
MsgBox "You can't select two, you can only choose one"
DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "Ir a"
End If
End Sub
```

This is the form:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HexB1.png)

This is the table, I have to add one to the "Votos" part.
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dM4I.png)

I hope you can help me out

Answer (score 1):

Your `If` statements are problematic. You are not properly building your logical statements. `&` concatenates two strings together. `AND` is a logical operator that links two conditions to the overall evaluation of a statement.

Checkboxes have a unique characteristic that lets `IF Me.Check1 = True Then` mean the same thing as `If Me.Check1 Then`. That's because the reference `Me.Check1` will evaluate to either a True or a False, exactly the parameter expected by the `If` statement.

---

The problem is, you cannot just use `&` to logically compare multiple tests. Your first `If` statement should read:

`IF(Me.Check1 = True AND Me.Check2 = True AND Me.Check3 = True) Then` or the simpler `If(Me.Check1 AND Me.Check2 AND Me.Check3) Then` where the evaluation of each reference will result in either True or False and the `AND` operator combines them together to evaluate the entire statement to a True or False.

Now that should work.

---

But I have to ask, do you really want to wait until the button is pressed to give feedback to the user? It's even simpler to build a toggling routine on the checkboxes:

In the `AfterUpdate` event of Checkbox 1, place:

```
If Me.Check1 Then
    Me.Check2 = False
    Me.Check3 = False
    Me.Check4 = False
End If
```

Now adjust that code for each of the other three checkboxes, first checking whether that checkbox is true, and if so, all others must be false.

This approach resets all checkboxes any time the user checks any checkbox. That way, you don't need to validate their selections during submission, making your code much easier to manage.

---

As for updating the vote tally, you will need two pieces of information and a sql `UPDATE` statement. The two pieces of info you need are: a unique way to identify which row in your table needs another vote and the current vote tally for that candidate/row. Do you know how to get that information? Do you know how to create and run an Update statement that will work regardless of who is being voted for? Hint: I would suggest using either a recordset or a query definition object, please take a stab at updating a record using one of those two methods, there should be tons of resources for both online.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the issue.

Comment: Although, my update statement doesn't work (It says sub doesn't exist): This is what I have  If Me.Check1 = True Then
     Update Candidatos
     Set Votos = Votos + 1
     WHERE [Nombre] = Marco
     End If

Comment: Your update is invalid and is not being called correctly. What is "Macro"? And you cannot use Votos = Votos + 1. Try researching how to execute an update sql statement with vba.